# Any REST API utilize cookies?

Tags: rest, cookies

I am doing a research regarding cookies usage in REST API. After some researches on the Internet, I still cannot find a REST API which return cookies as part of the REST response. WordPress use cookies for users authentication to the website's admin page, but cookies are not set or used on WordPress's REST API endpoints. So my question is, are there any REST API or REST services which utilize cookies?

Comment: I don't know of any, though it is possible until the communication is stateless. You can put even JWT into a httpOnly cookie if that's what you need.

Comment: hello @BillyWonka, do you find an answer?